# How to merge many lines in text file and combine one row in datatable C#?

Tags: c#, file, text, merge, datatable

I have a text file that contains something like the following, content blocks separated by white lines empty

```
Apple
System IOS
Version 12

Samsung
Android
Version 10,11
US, Canada

Nokia
KaiOS system
Unknow
```

and I would like to merge many lines to new one line in DataTable, keep original format , the content of DataTable will be that, just have 3 rows

[image]

Any advice for this, please feel free share with me.
Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to loop over the lines in the file and add a new row to the datatable each time you encounter an empty line.

Something like this

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
var col = dt.Columns.Add("Description", typeof(string));
StringBuilder linesBuffer = new StringBuilder();

// Read one line using the enumerable version for reading txt files
foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(@"e:\temp\datatable.txt"))
{
    // Check if we have reached an empty line 
    // If so then add it to databable and reset the buffer
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line) && linesBuffer.Length != 0)
    {
        dt.Rows.Add(lineBuffer.ToString());
        linesBuffer.Length = 0;
    }
    else
        // add to the buffer reinserting the newline
        linesBuffer.AppendLine(line);
}

// do not forget to add the last lines block
if(linesBuffer.Length > 0)
    dt.Rows.Add(linesBuffer.ToString());
```

Comment: Hi Steve, i got it. Besides, we will use "StringBuilder " to hold the value of lines. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: I have changed the test from IsNullOrEmpty to IsNullOrWhiteSpace to account for lines not empty but with some extra spaces or some control chars like \t

Comment: Hi Steve, when I run and debug it, it seems that the "StringBuilder" is added a new line/break line (\n) with the value being empty. Is this normal or can it be deleted?

Comment: The newline is added when you call AppendLine. If you don't want the last block to have a newline use Append instead. Or given the actual example decrement the length of the lineBuffer with _lineBuffer.Length-- (or -=2 if your endofline character is the string \r\n as in Windows OS)

Comment: Noted with thanks.